# String that contains all ascii characters

Tags: javascript, string, ascii

I want to create a string in JavaScript that contains all ascii characters. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "all"?  Alphabetical, or literally every character representation regardless of whether it has an actual written value?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My javascript is a bit rusty, but something like this:

```
s = '';
for( var i = 32; i <= 126; i++ )
{
    s += String.fromCharCode( i );
}
```

Not sure if the range is correct though.

**Edit:**
Seems it should be 32 to 127 then. Adjusted.

**Edit 2:**
Since char 127 isn't a printable character either, we'll have to narrow it down to 32 <= c <= 126, in stead of 32 <= c <= 127.

Comment: He did specify ASCII, and likely wants only printable characters, so you'll want to stick to 32 <= c <= 127.

Comment: Actually, character 127 isn't really printable, so 32 <= c < 127.

Comment: You are right Michael, I wasn't sure about the actual range of ASCII. Shame on me. :-/ But I've looked it up now, and it seems we should narrow it down to 32 to 126, since DEL is not a printable character either I believe. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ignacio: Well, there you go, you beat me to it.

Comment: I need all ascii chatacters. However, this helps, too. Thanks

Comment: @Gjorgji: which characters are you missing? Why do you think that those are not all?

Comment: @Joachim: I'll bet he's looking for "all printable Western European characters" or "all printable characters in my native script".  The definition of the word "ascii", especially when rendered in lowercase, has gotten a bit sloppy over the years, I've noticed.

Comment: There is also [Extended ASCII](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) with charcodes up to 255 (includes some accented letters like á, various symbols like ±, º, ≡ and also nbsp with the code 255)

Comment: @YakovL Extended ASCII isn't one character set. So the term is insufficient for almost all purposes. JavaScript uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the [Unicode character set](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) (as does Java, .NET, VB4/5/6/A/Script, …).

Answer (score 132):

```
const s = ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~';
```

Comment: I was looking for unicode, so someone else might also be: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïð

Comment: @Albert Hendriks That does *not* contain all Unicode code points. It doesn't even cover the first two [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block).

Comment: This question very clearly asks for a string containing all (printing) **ASCII** characters, which is feasible, as ASCII is a small, fixed set. If you're intending to cover *any* set of characters *beyond* ASCII, you must understand how Unicode classifies code points and use the proper solution for your problem case. If you're looking for "a string that contains all characters", you're doing things *wrong* - most likely, something *very* wrong.

Comment: I'm just trying to help anyone who might be looking for some unicode characters, like I was myself. Got here from Google.

Comment: I just wanted a string literal with all ASCII printable characters. Thanks [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=all+ascii+characters+in+one+string). Thanks @StuartP.Bentley.

Answer (score 6):

Just loop the character codes and convert each to a character:

```
var s = '';
for (var i=32; i<=127;i++) s += String.fromCharCode(i);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to put this here for reference. (takes about 13/100 to 26/100 of a ms on my computer to generate).

```
var allAsciiPrintables = JSON.stringify((Array.from(Array(126 + 32).keys()).slice(32).map((item) => {
    return String.fromCharCode(item);
})).join(''));
```

Decomposed:

```
var allAsciiPrintables = (function() {
    /* ArrayIterator */
    var result = Array(126 + 32).keys();    
    /* [0, 126 + 32] */
    result = Array.from(result);
    /* [32, 126 + 32] */
    result = result.slice(32);
    /* transform each item from Number to its ASCII as String. */
    result = result.map((item) => {
        return String.fromCharCode(item);
    });
    /* convert from array of each string[1] to a single string */
    result = result.join('');

    /* create an escaped string so you can replace this code with the string 
       to avoid having to calculate this on each time the program runs */
    result = JSON.stringify(result);

    /* return the string */
    return result;
})();
```

The most efficient solution(if you do want to generate the whole set each time the script runs, is probably)(takes around 3/100-35/100 of a millisecond on my computer to generate).

```
var allAsciiPrintables = (() => {
    var result = new Array(126-32);
    for (var i = 32; i <= 126; ++i) {
        result[i - 32] = (String.fromCharCode(i));        
    }
    return JSON.stringify(result.join(''));
})();
```

strangely, this is only 3-10 times slower than assigning the string literal directly(with backticks to tell javascript to avoid most backslash parsing).

```
var x;
var t;

t = performance.now();
x = '!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~';
t = performance.now() - t;
console.log(t);
```

.

Answer (score 2):

This is a version written in python. Gives all ASCII characters in order as a single string.

```py
all_ascii = ''.join(chr(k) for k in range(128))  # 7 bits
all_chars = ''.join(chr(k) for k in range(256))  # 8 bits
printable_ascii = ''.join(chr(k) for k in range(128) if len(repr(chr(k))) == 3)


>>> print(printable_ascii)
' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'
```

The last string here, `printable_ascii` contains only those characters that contain no escapes (i.e. have length == 1). The chars like:  `\x05, \x06` or `\t, \n` which does not have its own glyph in your system's font, are filtered out.

`len(repr(chr(k))) == 3` includes 2 quotes that come from `repr` call.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing several appends:

```js
var s = Array.apply(null, Array(127-32))
  .map(function(x,i) {
    return String.fromCharCode(i+32);
  }).join("");
  document.write(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ES6 one liner:

```js
asciiChars = Array.from({ length: 95 }, (e, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 32)).join('');

console.log(asciiChars)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = '';// empty string declear
for( var i = 32; i <= 126; i++ )
{
    str = str + String.fromCharCode( i ); /* this method received one integer and
```

convert it into a  ascii characters and store it str variable one by one by using
string concatenation method. The loop start for 32 and end 126 */
}

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version in coffeescript

```
require 'fluentnode'

all_Ascii = ->
  (String.fromCharCode(c) for c in  [0..255])

describe 'all Ascii', ->

  it 'all_Ascii', ->
    all_Ascii.assert_Is_Function()
    all_Ascii().assert_Size_Is 256
    all_Ascii()[0x41].assert_Is 'A'
    all_Ascii()[66  ].assert_Is 'B'
    all_Ascii()[50  ].assert_Is '2'
    all_Ascii()[150 ].assert_Is String.fromCharCode(150)
```

Comment: The question asked for *printable* ASCII.