# How to write ascii characters 0-31 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, ascii

I noticed here at [String that contains all ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444447/string-that-contains-all-ascii-characters) they skip the first ASCII characters. Then [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) they list a bunch of control codes like `\cA`, but they only work for regular expressions. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript) lists about 10 such as `\n` and `\r`. Wondering if you can write the other ones in backslash notation somehow, or you must resort to unicode `\u{...}` or hex `\x{...}`.

Comment: You have to use the numeric escapes for the others.

Comment: See this too in case you haven't: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters. Specifically, the table in the section.

Comment: I'd definitely call `\x0A` "backslash notation"? Not sure what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-StringLiteral) (of course :-) ), specifically where it talks about [*SingleEscapeCharacter*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-SingleEscapeCharacter):

> SingleEscapeCharacter :: one of
>   
>   ' " \ b f n r t v

Ignoring `'`, `"`, and `\` which aren't control characters, that gives us:

- `\b` is backspace (character 8)
- `\f` is formfeed (character 12)
- As you know, `\n` is newline and `\r` is carriage return
- `\t` is tab (character 9)
- `\v` is vertical tab (character 11)

So other than those six, you have to use `\uNNNN`, `\xXX`, or `\u{N+}` (ES2015+) for the others. Or of course use typing tricks to type them literally, which may work in some cases but is almost certainly a Very Bad Idea™. :-)

---

Being pedantic, these aren't ASCII, they're Unicode. But this is a place where Unicode intentionally overlaps ASCII, so...

Comment: You might want to mention the deprecated [`LegacyOctalEscapeSequence`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-additional-syntax-string-literals) that allows to omit the `x` or `u` prefix

Comment: @Bergi - ...or we could try to let it slip out of the general consciousness... ;-)