# Sketchy CDATA code written in Python's byte format

Tags: javascript, python, cdata, phishing

People of StackOverflow, what do these things do? Excuse me for having such little knowledge of Python.

**source (please use line wrap):** view-source:clipfull.github.io (phishing site's source code)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually minified Javascript.
The Javascript string escaping just work the same as in Python (cf [question about it in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006360/11384184)).

I wrote a script to deminify it, and it is a login page.